# BootStrap 3 Progress Bar Label Cut Off

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a progress bar which the text is fully shown no matter the size of the progress bar. I'm not sure what options to add so that the text for the span under Java Application Development can be larger that the progress bar itself.

```css
.resume {
    width: 816px;
    margin: 48px 48px 48px 48px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 4px;
}

.name {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.summary h2, .skills h2, .professionalhistory h2 {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.skills {
    line-height: 13px;
}

.skills p {
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.progress {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.progress span {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
}

.progress-bar {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 13px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

.progress-bar span {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="skills" style="line-height: 13px;">
    <h2 style="text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 24px;">Possesses Advance Knowledge Of</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <p style="margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;">Java Application Development</p>
            <div class="progress" style="text-align: left; position: relative; height: 13px; margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:7.69%; padding: 0px 10px;">
                    <span style="display: inline;">1 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is the following. This is what changed

```
.progress-bar span {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        color: black;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0%;
        transform: translate(0%,-50%);
}
```

```css
.resume {
    width: 816px;
    margin: 48px 48px 48px 48px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 4px;
}

.name {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.summary h2, .skills h2, .professionalhistory h2 {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.skills {
    line-height: 13px;
}

.skills p {
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.progress {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.progress-bar {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 13px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

.progress-bar span {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    color: black;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(0%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="skills">
    <h2>Possesses Advance Knowledge Of</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <p>Microsoft Operating Systems</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Microsoft Office SharePoint Services</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:53.85%">
                    <span>7 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Microsoft Active Directory</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Microsoft Exchange Services</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Microsoft Office Suite</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Cisco Networking Devices</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>VMWare Products</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:69.23%">
                    <span>9 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <p>Project Management</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:38.46%">
                    <span>5 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Personnel Management</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:69.23%">
                    <span>9 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Training and Development</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:69.23%">
                    <span>9 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Customer Service Relations</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:61.54%">
                    <span>8 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Performance Management</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:69.23%">
                    <span>9 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Oral Expressive</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100.00%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Critical Thinker</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100.00%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <p>Complex Problem Solver</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100.00%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Attention to Detail</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100.00%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Sandler Sales Concepts</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:23.08%">
                    <span>3 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Visual Basic for Applications</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:69.23%">
                    <span>9 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Java Application Development</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:7.69%">
                    <span>1 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Microsoft Visual Studio</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:84.62%">
                    <span>11 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Microsoft SharePoint Designer</p>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:38.46%">
                    <span>5 Years</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like how it all displayed now but how do I take you concept left align all the labels?

Comment: Hey i revised my solution. It might need some left spacing/padding but you get the gist.

Comment: That perfectly! Thank you!